# Optimization in R: what is the difference between a constructor and a wrapper?

Tags: r, optimization

I am going over the following code from Roger Peng's [course](https://rdpeng.github.io/Biostat776/lecture-scoping-rules-of-r.html#application-optimization); the author is building a function to calculate the negative log-likelihood, `make.NegLogLik`, but he does so using what he calls a "**constructor function**". Peng uses the constructor function because `make.NegLogLik` will later be optimized, and in this way, it will easier to hold a parameter constant.

I can see that the constructor function "contains" another function, that is, the function actually calculating the negative log-likelihood.

```r
make.NegLogLik <- function(data, fixed = c(FALSE, FALSE)) {
  params <- fixed
  function(p) {
    params[!fixed] <- p
    mu <- params[1]
    sigma <- params[2]
    
    ## Calculate the Normal density
    a <- -0.5*length(data)*log(2*pi*sigma^2)
    b <- -0.5*sum((data-mu)^2) / (sigma^2)
    -(a + b)
  } 
}


set.seed(1)
normals <- rnorm(100, 1, 2)
nLL <- make.NegLogLik(normals)
nLL
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

In that, it looks *similar* to a **wrapper**, for example:

```r
toy_function <- function(x,y,z,w) {
  sum_coordinates <- sum(x+y) + sum(z+w)
  distance <- w-y
  penalty <- sum_coordinates + distance
  return(penalty)
}

wrapper = function(args){
  toy_function(x = args[1],
                 y = args[2],
                 z = args[3],
                 w = args[4])
}

# the function takes a vector
vec <- c(1,1,0,0)
wrapper(vec)
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Question**

I have looked up "constructor function" in R but all the results coming up refer to object-oriented programming. I was wondering what "constructor function" means in the context of the optimization example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, the return value of the function is another function. So `make.NegLogLik()` *constructs* another function.

In the second example, the return value of `wrapper()` is the *return value* of `toy_function()`. So you can use it directly where you would use `toy_function()`. Usually this is just to change the interface or set defaults for a function you don't own.

In other words, usage looks something like this. Compare the steps for the constructor vs the steps for the wrapper. For the constructor, you must actually call the returned function to get the value you want.

```
my_negloglik_fun <- make.NegLogLik(data = some_data)
negloglik <- my_negloglik_fun(c(param1, param2))

penalty <- wrapper(args = list(x, y, z, w))
```

This has a number of use cases; one example might be that you want to iterate a function over many sets of inputs. Using a constructor to get that function means that you don't have to specify other arguments when iterating. For the function constructed by `make.NegLogLik()`, you can test out many options for `mu` and `sigma` without having to pass the `data` in each time (and in fact, that is what functions like `optim()` want to do)

Comment: Thank you for the very clear explanation.